# Is this a vector field (abbreviation)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, definition, vector-analysis

I'm new to this notation:
$$
F=(F_1,F_2, \dots, F_m)
$$
where $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.

No boldface or variables. Is this a abbreviation for a vector field?

I mean, is the explicit form actually a vector $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and 
$$
F(\mathbf{x})=(F_1(\mathbf{x}), F_2(\mathbf{x}), \dots, F_m(\mathbf{x})) \iff
$$
$$
F(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)=(F_1(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n), F_2(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n), \dots, F_m(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n))
$$
in $\mathbb{R}^m$?
Is this a correct interpretation of the notation?

Comment: Yep, and each $\;F_i\;$ is a scalar function: $\;F_i:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't describe $F$ as a vector field. It's just a function.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think that is precisely the definition of vector field in general.

Comment: @DonAntonio The problem is that $n$ may not be $m$, so that the function does not really assign a vector from $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @edm Well, yes: that seems to be a condition among several authors. Perhaps it is matter of definition, that the map must be from $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ to itself. Thanks.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Do you mean for a vector field we have $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ but a vector function is actually $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, where $n\neq m$?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The long answer is that it's not quite right to think of vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, although it's true that we can identify vector fields with such functions if we want to; there's a more general definition of what a vector field on a manifold is that's a bit more subtle than this.